# SELECT records that were not yesterday

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following CTE

```
;
WITH cte 
AS
(
    select t.UserId, t.Date
    from (select 
            Date
            , UserId
            , row_number() over(partition by UserId order by Date desc) as RowNumber
          from dbo.Income_Expenses) as t
    where t.RowNumber = 1       
)
```

If I make a selection on it, I'll get the following results:

```
Date                        UserId  RowNumber
2015-05-10 00:00:00.000     6       1
2015-05-08 00:00:00.000     7       1
```

Basically I get the last record that has been inserted by every user.

Now, when I make a selection on the CTE, I want to get the records that are older than the day before yesterday.
I.E. Today is May 10th; I want all the records that are from May 8th and later. (8th, 7th, etc, but not 9th and 10th).

So I tried some expression with DATEADD, DATEDIFF and none of them worked.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this condition to the cte: `and datediff(day, date, getDate()) >= 2`

Comment: Yes it's working now, but the difference must be 1 not 2. Still, thank you :)